# How do I add a volume control in my MPMoviePlayerController instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, mpmovieplayercontroller

The below is the code which opens a video on a button press. Everything is fine but I want to add a volume control for my video player. Is there a default feature from the MPMoviePlayerController that I can just enable, or do I have to use the slider from the objects library , drag and drop it, and the adjust the volume according to the slider value?

```
NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"space-time" ofType:@"mp4"];


moviePlayer= [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];

moviePlayer.fullscreen = YES;


[moviePlayer play];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to add a volume view use this code
make a uiview in your viewcontroller of about 200width by 30height,
drop outlet for that view (view1) after that

```
MPVolumeView *volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view1.bounds] ;
 [self.view1 addSubview:volumeView];
```

volume slider will show up in that view1

Comment: No, the slider is not added. Where do you u think the slider should appear ? right below the play button ? well its not coming .

Comment: Still no gain :(. In which view controller do I add this view? My video opens when I press a button. You are saying that i should add this view1 to the view controller where my button is ?

Comment: please note volumeview will only appear in device

Comment: Okay. Not on simulator ?

Comment: try playing video from avplayer.